# Style of application changed after upgrading to supportlib:v7

Tags: android, material-design

After i upgraded support library from v4 to v7 the syle of Buttons changed.

Even when use an ImageButton and set View.setVisibility(View.Gone) it stills shows the location of it by highlighting like picture below.

[image]

---

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#F44336" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="#E53935"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/find" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: share the xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing "location highlight" because colors of background and textview are different. Background is in this color:

```
android:background="#F44336"
```

and linear layout is:

```
android:background="#E53935"
```

Those colors are both red and very similar but yet different. Remove background from TextView and "location highlight" will be removed because only layout background color will stay.